# Show a wordpress page in Facebook Page as a Site, using app_data paremeter

Tags: facebook, wordpress, mod-rewrite

Good fellas,

My client requested a site in Wordpress, for now I will call www.example.com, but he wanted the site displays it too as a Facebook Page. Because the server with SSL is for other domain www.serverssl.com, I put the wordpress site at a relative directory on serverssl, so I have this:

> www.serverssl.com -> Document Root: /var/www/html/ (using ssl)
>  
>   www.example.com    -> Document Root:  /var/www/html/example/site
>   For Facebook Page  -> www.serverssl.com/example/site  (using ssl)

Because Wordpress is configured at relative path, at first time when I tried to get at Facebook Page it didn't work. So I've added some lines to .htaccess at Document Root of Wordpress:

> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443 
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

So, if I tried to reach www.facebook/com/Client/app_00000000/ the iframe redirect to www.example.com so works fine.

Well, the client now wants other think: He wants a link to enter a Facebook Page that shows a specific page in wordpress. So I thought use app_data parameter, like this:

> www.facebook.com/Client/app_00000000?app_data=specificpage

then at header.php of wordpress' theme evalutes the $_REQUEST['signed_request'] parameter in order to search the app_data and then redirect to specificpage.

> But the header.php nevers see the REQUEST send by Facebook,

I tried with the .htaccess:

> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^signed_request=(.*)$ [NC]
>   RewriteRule . http://www.example.com/%{QUERY_STRING} [R,L]

Still does not sent the signed_request.

Any idea how reach send signed_request through redirect?

PD: Sorry my bad english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load the page in a Facebook iframe it will always pass the signed_request on the first load.

I am not too great with mod-rewrite but I would suggest verifying the rewritecond on the signed request. Other values may have being transferred as well causing your condition to fail.